# How to stop a running download after a system reboot

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-cursor, android-download-manager

Here is the situation:

1. I start a download
2. I restart the device (to test the robustness of the app)
3. I use a boot receiver to be notified of the restart
4. In the onReceive method I call the clearDownloadsAfterReboot() method:

   ```
    @Override
      public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        clearDownloadsAfterReboot(context);
       }
   ```
5. The clearDownloadsAfterReboot() method get called and tries to remove the downloads like so:

   ```
   private void clearDownloadsAfterReboot(final Context context){
      //Added delay to make sure download has started
      new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

           DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
           DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
           query.setFilterById (DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING|DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING|DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED);
           Cursor c = manager.query(query);
           // -------> c.getCount() returns 0 despite the download being visible
           while(c.moveToNext()) {
               //This never executes because c has a count of 0
               int removedInt = manager.remove(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID)));
           }
       }
     }, 45000); 
   }
   ```
6. The cursor returns 0 so the remove() method is never called, but, I can see the download running in the status bar so there is at least 1 download running.

**My questions in a nutshell:** How do I stop running downloads after a reboot? And, why would the manager.query() method return a cursor which has 0 results when there is a download running?

I know there are other question regarding stopping downloads but these have not been able to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using the method setFilterById() passing it a combination of statuses from the DownloadManager when that method actually expects an enumeration of downloads ids. So either pass the downloads ids or use the setFilterByStatus() method with the combination of flags you currently used.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think that you're right. Now that I've changed the method to setFilterByStatus() the cursor returns the correct amount of downloads. And, it does appear that the download has stopped (it stays at 0%), however, the notification of the 'in progress download' won't clear itself from the notifications tray once it has been stopped. Do you know why that would happen? Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit for the first part of this answer goes to @Lukesprog

I needed to use `setFilterByStatus()` instead of `setFilterById()`. After exchanging these two methods I was able to successfully stop the download and the manager.query() method returned a cursor containing the correct amount of downloads.

However, for some reason the notification which showed the progress of the download didn't clear after the download had been stopped. In order to clear the notification you need to call `manager.remove(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID)));` **twice**.